# Color code value converted to 2 digit numeral

Tags: c, math

I am working on a project that changes the color of an LED to the color of an RGB value input by the user.

The way the program works right now to change the brightness of each color is by providing it a number `0`-`1` so `0` is fully on `1` is fully off `0.50` is 50% brightness etc.

It seems kind of backwards providing a `0` for on but that's just the way the code is written. My question is how would I convert the values `0`-`255` to the `0`-`99` I have done the math by dividing the 3 digit number by `2.58` which gives me the proper number if it was `1` for on and `0` for off, but since its backwards how would I obtain the opposite of this?

Would this be the remainder? So for example `240`/`2.58`=`93` the remainder is `7` so is that the number I would use? Math was never my strong point unfortunately. I know this question does not pertain to a certain language but I am going to tag it with `C` since that's what it is going to be written in. If someone could provide an example of getting the remainder of a number using `C` that would be awesome. I know of the modulo operator but I don't think that would work in my case but I could be wrong.

Comment: `1 - colour / 2.58`, wouldn't it be that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double mapNumbers(double x, long xMin, long xMax, long yMin, long yMax)
{
  return ((double)(x - xMin) * (yMax - yMin)) / ((double)(xMax - xMin)) + yMin;
}
```

Use the above function:

you can map `x` which is between `0-255` and get the corresponding number from `0-99` - infact between any range of numbers and any other range of numbers:

so:
   `mapNumbers(10/*assuming this is x*/, 0, 255, 0, 99);`

Answer (score 1):

Well, to convert from a 0 - 1 range to a 0 - 255 range, just multiple by 255. To do it inversely, just subtract the first value from 1.

```
result = (1 - x) * 255;
```